# How does Solr filter on fields in documents

Tags: solr, lucene

I am currently doing POC on a collection with ~5000 fields/ document. All the fields have (stored,indexed attributes as true). I am interested in only displaying ~5 fields from each of the matching documents.

I am trying to understand if Solr brings all the ~5k fields of a matched document into memory from the .fdt files and discards the rest to only keep the 5 fields I am interested in? 
My concern is with the memory usage if it keeps bringing all the fields in memory.

Any light in this regard will be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In your managed-schema.xml or schema.xml, each field has a 'stored' attribute and an 'indexed' attribute. The indexed attribute allows the field to be found in full-text search. The stored attribute stores the data so that it can be displayed later on.

It sounds like if you only want to display 5 fields and are worried about space, the solution would be to set those 5 fields to stored=true and the rest of your fields to stored=false while keeping all fields set to indexed=true. This will minimize the memory that SOLR will use up while still allowing full-text search.